# Accessing the index in Python for loops with namedtuple

Tags: python, iteration

If I have a list of int, and I want to iterate through it getting elements and the index, then I can do this:

```
for idx, val in enumerate(ints):
    print idx, val
```

How do I do the same thing with a list of namedtuple?

```
Point = namedtuple("Point", ['x', 'y'])
#Append points
points.append(p1)
...

#This gives me the x,y coordinates from the points, not the iteration index.
for i,p in points:
    print(str(i) + ' ' + str(p))
```

Comment: i don't get it, you know how to use enumerate with a list of ints, but not with a list of whatevers?

Comment: Yep.  I've just been staring at the code too long.  Couldn't see that enumerate :)

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
for i, p in enumerate(points):
    print(str(i) + ' ' + str(p))
```

`enumerate()` takes care of adding the indexes to any iterable that's passed as parameter.

Answer (score 2):

You still need to use `enumerate` if you want to access the index at each iteration. The contents of the list don't really change the behavior of the standard iteration, except to *allow* constructions like `for x, y in points` when the list contains iterables.

```
for i, p in enumerate(points):
    print(str(i) + ' ' + str(p))
```

---

For posterity: from at least Python 2.7, you can nest your tuple unpacking like this:

```
for i, (x, y) in enumerate(points):
    print('%d (%s, %s)'.format(i, x, y))
```